# Add an element in set<Object1> of List<Object2> in java collections

Tags: java, collections, java-6

I have 2 model Person and address and getting data from db using resulset and resulset is getting (Personid, PersonName, AddrerssId, AddressName) values

```
 Class Person{
    int id;
    String name;
    Set<Address> address;
    // setter and getter
    }

Class Address{
int id;
String address;
//setter and getter
}
```

Now i iterate reslutset so when a person is having more than 1 address then add only addressid and address for same personId in set of address.

```
while(rs.next){
ListIterator<Person> itr = personList.listIterator();
Boolean flag = false;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Person p = (Person)itr.next();
    if(/*person id match from resultset*/){
    //**add only addressid and address for same personId in set of address**
    }    
  }
  if(!flag){
  //add all details from resultset.
  }
}
```

I want to add only address id and address in set object of address if person id is found during iteration. How will i do this. I am using java6 in application.

Answer (score 0):

Use ResultSet [getInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(java.lang.String)) and compare `int`s:

```
 if (personList.getID() == rs.getInt("ID"))
```

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object as an int

Comment: I want to add only address id and address in set object of address if person id is found during iteration.

Comment: I have put up below code inside of If condition 
     ListIterator<BaseLineProduct> blpitr = productList.listIterator();
      while (blpitr.hasNext()) {
       BaseLineProduct baseLineProduct = (BaseLineProduct) blpitr.next();
       blpitr.add(blp);
      }